# SharePoint Workflow, Approver Lookup List

Tags: workflow, infopath, form, content-approval

I am trying to create an approval process for InfoPath Form in a Form Library, for SharePoint 2010. I currently have a list of approvers in a list on my SharePoint site called Approvers.

This list then populates a drop down list box on the InfoPath form.

The user will select which approver they want and the workflow process will begin with them.
My question is how to have the approval process lookup on my form, which person was selected and then begin the process with that particular individual?

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any version number on this. I am assuming SharePoint 2010.

In SharePoint Designer 2010 create a new workflow. Set it to run when an item is modified, if needed. Under the actions item click "Start Approval Process" in designer a new step will be added to the Editor pane. To the right you will see the option to configure who the Approver will be. I have attached an image from one of my workflows.

[image]

I think you will find these links helpful.
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/understand-approval-workflows-in-sharepoint-2010-HA101857172.aspx

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0NcqLRNN4-Q

Comment: Thanks Robert. I think the problem lies in the fact that drop down list of the approvers is being populated from an external data source (i.e. another SharePoint List).

Comment: Can you set a variable to the value? Provided it is not in another site collection you should be able to use the Lookup Item in Another List step to find your value and then set a variable.

Comment: Good thought. I will have to give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

please check this http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/. Maybe your solution it's very simple if you test with the next tip:

Pay attention because the WF not search in your InfoPath form, you have to publish your field Approvers (bind with Approvers List) in your form, like a column in your SharePoint Library for Infopath Forms. See that please http://www.marclenferna.com/blog/archive/2009/01/18/how-to.-publish-your-infopath-form-to-sharepoint--a.aspx

Next in your SP Designer WF, you can see the column in the Forms Library, and use in the WF condition.

Bye

Comment: Thanks Andres, I already have the Approvers Field bound to my Approvers List, my difficulty is getting it set up in the workflow. In other words creating a  workflow lookup.